# Text misaligned when the responsive navigation button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just testing the Responsive Top Navigation example provided by W3Schools, I've done a minor modification on the internal style sheet so the text `Home` will move to the center of the menu and it misaligned when I click on the navigation button.

Why would this happen and how to fix this ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    ul.topnav {
      text-align: center;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    ul.topnav li {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
    }
    ul.topnav li a {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: 0.3s;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    ul.topnav li a:hover {
      background-color: #555;
    }
    ul.topnav li.icon {
      display: none;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
      ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
      }
      ul.topnav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
      ul.topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: top move because your `li.icon` switch between `position: relative` to `position: absolute`

Comment: @SteevePitis Thank you, is there exist a solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in comment, the problem is because your `li.icon` switch between `position: relative` to `position: absolute`

You have to fix it to `position:absolute`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    ul.topnav {
      text-align: center;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    ul.topnav li {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
    }
    ul.topnav li a {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: 0.3s;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    ul.topnav li a:hover {
      background-color: #555;
    }
    ul.topnav li.icon {
      display: none;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
      ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
      }
      ul.topnav li.icon {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
      ul.topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ul.topnav li.icon is floated when its active.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    ul.topnav {
      text-align: center;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    ul.topnav li {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
    }
    ul.topnav li a {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: 0.3s;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    ul.topnav li a:hover {
      background-color: #555;
    }
    ul.topnav li.icon {
      display: none;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
      ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
      }
      ul.topnav li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
      ul.topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
      }

      ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  </div>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
</script>

</body>


</html>
```

http://codepen.io/twotoan/pen/zKaBzK

Is that what you're trying to achieve?